# How to set the column order of DTO properties programatically

Tags: c#, data-annotations, dto

I am having simple DTO class. I would like to dynamically set the column order of this dto properties when the results are stored into excel.

```
Public class Student
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

I know there is a way using DataAnnotation Column Order Attribute on each property inside DTO. But is there a way to handle this using code to set the column order of DTO.

I am using simple web application and added System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation Reference.

If there is a work around without using DataAnnotation to set the column order using code that will be great

Comment: just wondering, how the columns order will make a difference while storing in the db?

Comment: I am writing to excel. Sorry to say about db. So i want data to be correct written inside excel based on column order

Comment: Members of a type is not guaranteed to be retrieved using reflection in any particular order. Usually they will be returned in the order they were declared, but not always. As such, the code involved will need to have some sort of guaranteeing the right order, hence the attributes. Any particular reason you don't want to use the attribute you say fixes this?

Comment: I can use attributes using programatically. We dont want developers to also force to provide column orders when creating dto. They will just create dto with properties and i can dyamically set the column order

Answer (score 0):

What about using a static array inside your class or in a different class which list all columns in the order you want, and while saving to excel you loop through this array first to get columns in the correct order.

Something like that:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<string> OrderedProperties => new List<string> { "LastName", "FirstName", "Id" };
}

public class DataAccess
{
    public void SaveStudentToExcel()
    {
        var student = new Student(); // instead of new this should be your object filled with real data.
        foreach (var propName in student.OrderedProperties)
        {
            var val = student.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(student, null);

            // new cell in excel => with val and propName then save
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1030181 updated my answer with simple sample code.